# Using feature class name as name in output (buffer_analysis)

Tags: arcpy

I'm pretty new in python, and I'm trying to iterate through a list of feature classes, and perform a buffer on each feature class. So I've done this:

```
import arcpy  
from arcpy import env  
env.workspace = "C:/EsriPress/Python/Data/Midterm/Oil_project.gdb"  
env.overwriteOutput = True  
fclist = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses("", "Polyline", "Well_Data")  

for fc in fclist  
buffer = arcpy.Buffer_analysis(fc, fcname_buffer, "75 FEET")
```

However, I want each output file name to be the original feature class name with _buffer at the end. For example, the name of the first feature class in the list is Well_A_BB05.shp. I want the output to be "Well_A_BB05_buffer". I can't get this to work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the `arcpy.Buffer_analysis()` set your output to be `'{}_buffer'.format(fc)` which will add your feature class name from `fc` in front of the `_buffer` text e.g. if your feature class is called "Line3" the output buffer feature class would be called "Line3_buffer"

```py
import arcpy  
from arcpy import env  
env.workspace = "C:/EsriPress/Python/Data/Midterm/Oil_project.gdb"  
env.overwriteOutput = True  

fclist = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses("", "Polyline", "Well_Data")  

for fc in fclist: 
    arcpy.Buffer_analysis(fc, '{}_buffer'.format(fc), "75 FEET")
```